# How can we set a group of fonts using fontFamily props in React Native?

Tags: react-native, font-family

As in css , we can set like this :

```
font-family:"Times New Roman",Georgia,Serif;
```

But in RN , we can just set one font ,

```
fontFamily: 'MidPlane00v3.1',
```

How can we use it like css?
I need to show multiple bytes Chinese words using font rollback mechanism!

Comment: for what purpose do u want to do that is it for using different font styles in a single word?

Comment: @Adarsh Sreeram ,I want to show some multiple bytes Chinese words in one sentence!For example,there are two font files, MidPlane00 and MidPlane02,they contain different Chinese words,if these different words in one `<Text/>`,how can we let them display corrently?What I can only think of is using fontFamily to set a group of fonts!

Comment: Did you come up with a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't set `font-family` in react-native like you would in CSS. This is because in CSS what's happening is that the browser will try to fetch the first `font-family` and in case it can't it will try the next defined alternative, like stated in [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-family.php)

In react-native, this isn't an issue because you'll add the `font-family` to the app's native assets folder, guarantying the `font-family`'s presence on the app. If you want a further explanation on why, you can take a look at [React Native](https://reactnative.dev/docs/text#limited-style-inheritance) documentation.

And if you want to know how to add custom font-family to the project, you can follow this [guide](https://blog.logrocket.com/adding-custom-fonts-react-native/)